# Issue with datetime string format

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

Im trying to convert a datetime object to a string but it does not seem to give me the desired output.

```
from datetime import datetime

cur_time = datetime.now()
last_runtime = cur_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+%Z") 
print(last_runtime)
```

**My current output:**

```
2021-10-13T09:09:27.824592+
```

**My desired output:**

```
2021-10-13T09:09:27.825+00:00
```

Comment: `datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat()`? Please have another look at the docs, especially the difference between [naive and aware datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects), as well as [formatting directives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

Comment: The title is very misleading because the problem has nothing to do with converting to a `str`.

Comment: That does not give me the desired output. It gives me: `2021-10-13T09:15:25.472419` I want `2021-10-13T09:15:25.472+00:00``

Comment: @mapf: `strftime` does exactly that, converting datetime to string.

Comment: @ManCity10 revised my comment, please have another look...

Comment: @MrFuppes that's my point. The question reads as if there would be a problem with converting, but really it's an issue with the format of the date and not the conversion to a `str` type.

Comment: @MrFuppes `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

Comment: @mapf ok that's basically what I mean by "have a look at naive vs aware datetime and formatting directives" ^^

Comment: @MrFuppes fair enough. "Proper" simply implies something that isn't there--the desired result is entirely subjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.astimezone()` and small z on the format string:

```
from datetime import datetime

cur_time = datetime.now()
last_runtime = cur_time.astimezone().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z") 
last_runtime = "{0}:{1}".format(
  last_runtime[:-2],
  last_runtime[-2:]
)
print(last_runtime)
```

Comment: @Almost, I have this right now: `2021-10-13T09:17:04.453691+0200` I want `2021-10-13T09:17:04.453691+02:00`

Comment: there is no prebuilt function but you can have a workaround like in my edited answer